# Why doesn't OpenCL support recursion?

Tags: recursion, opencl

I am currently working on a OpenCL project and I am wonder why it does not support recursion. Is it related to parallelism?

Answer (score 7):

It is related to the target hardware, I think. To support recursion requires several hardware features that certain classes of OpenCL devices (ie. GPUs) don't have. Without them, maintaining a call stack and doing indirect code branching isn't practical. NVIDIA don't support recursion on all their CUDA capable hardware for the same reason.

Comment: Talonmies: Recursion is supported for device functions on compute capability 2.x devices.

Comment: @ashwin: I am well aware of that, which is why I said "NVIDIA don't support recursion on *all* their CUDA capable hardware". They support it on some, ie Fermi and Kepler...

Comment: It is possible to implement recursion without hardware support if the maximum depth of recursion is known at compile-time. This can be easily done [using macros in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77470186/975097), and probably in OpenCL as well.

Answer (score 4):

Its not OpenCL, Its GPU hardware.  AMD had laid out a future Instruction Set Architecture 
that  will support recursion. GPUs have large numbers of registers (up to 32 K).  So
be careful of what to ask for and get. Push/Pop of 32K registers, for a recursive call, will not be speedy.