# Does RenderScript support recursion?

Tags: renderscript

[OpenCL doesn't support recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050708/why-doesnt-opencl-support-recursion). [CUDA does, but only from a certain version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644809/does-cuda-support-recursion). Initial search indicated RenderScript *does* support recursion, but I couldn't find anything explicit.

Does RenderScript support recursive function calls?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it does.  However, using this will limit a script to processors capable of recursion.

Comment: so what happens when you run this script on such devices? will it just use only the CPU ?

Comment: The script will run, but be limited to the processors which support the features the script uses. So in the case where you use recursion, then run on a device with a GPU that does not support it, it will run on the CPU.

Comment: yes, so on unsupported GPUs, it will run on the CPU instead.